# Unable to install AMD-GPU-PRO drivers

Tags: drivers, apt, package-management, dependencies, amd-graphics

I'm running on Ubuntu 18.10 and just got a new graphics card, RX580. I downloaded the latest package from AMD's site and tried to do `./amdgpu-pro-install`. This returns an error saying:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 amdgpu : Depends: amdgpu-core (= 18.40-676022) but 18.20-606296 is to be installed
 amdgpu-pro : Depends: amdgpu-pro-core (= 18.40-676022) but 18.20-606296 is to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Answer (score 0):

My experience:
with ubuntu 18.04 runnning on hardware amd ryzen7 and saphire radeon rx 560 45W.
amdgpu-pro-18.50-7084488 successfully installed with Linux-kernel 4.20 but did not work (black screen). With that kernel the resume from suspend also did not work (system freeze).
I return to the kernel 4.19.1 and all works perfectly.

Comment: This does not solve the issue, there are plenty of workarounds rather than just blindly downgrading the kernel